# Where is my PATH variable being set?

Tags: bash, java, environment-variables, bashrc, .profile

I'm trying to set my path variable to look like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/jgrande/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin
```

And for some reasons, no matter what file I edit, the variable always ends up looking like this (with the java path repeating a bunch of times):

```
PATH=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/home/jgrande/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/home/jgrande/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/bin
```

I've tried to edit my personal `.bashrc` and `.profile` as well as `/etc/environment`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, and set it in `/etc/profile.d`. Now, there is `jdk.sh` in `/etc/profile.d` where the PATH variable is identical to the incorrect one I posted above. However, I tried to comment out the line and even remove `jdk.sh` altogether and that still didn't fix it.

Otherwise, I've noticed that if I log in as another user, I'll have the correct PATH variable, and don't have the messed up one with java being repeated a bunch of times.

So, I was wondering, where else could my PATH variable be defined that I haven't checked yet?

Comment: Do your .bash_profile (or .profile) and/or your .bashrc source other files?

Comment: Nope, neither my .profile or .bashrc are sourcing other files.

Comment: It's weird: files in /etc/profile.d are sourced for *every* login bash session.  So your other user should have these as well. Why don't you just set your "correct" PATH explicitly in your .profile?

Comment: Yeah, I just did that, which worked. I'm still interested to see what was overriding the other files (bash.bashrc, /etc/profile, etc.).

Comment: It looks like like you got `jdk/bin:jgrande/bin` at the beginning, and `jdk/jre/bin` at the end, both happening twice. I don't know what "jgrande" is but it looks suspicious. I'd search for that in /etc/profile.d

Comment: Do `grep -P '^[^#]*\KPATH' /etc/{profile,bash.bashrc,environment} ~/{.bashrc,.profile,.pam_environment} 2>/dev/null` and add the output to your question..

Comment: sorry, it took years to answer. Cross-posting from https://stackoverflow.com/a/77740722/847349 : 

ndeed, finding out where some part is defined requires too much effort.

Thus, I’ve codified the heuristics into a tool:

https://github.com/d-led/pathdebug

`pathdebug PATH` and you'll get the sources, and whether the directories exist or are duplicates

Answer (score 10):

The PATH could be set in any of the various files bash reads when it starts. To find them all, run this:

```bash
grep --color -H 'PATH=' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login \
                     ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile \
                     /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null
```

Those are the standard ones. If you are also sourcing other files from one of those, things can get more complex.

Anyway, to fix it—assuming you haven't done anything to the global files in `/etc/`—you can run this:

```bash
sed -i '/PATH=/d' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases
```

That will delete any lines setting `PATH` from those files. Now, add the right one in the right place:

```bash
pp='PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/jgrande/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin'
[[ -e '~/.bash_profile' ]] && echo "$pp" >> ~/bash_profile ||
                              echo "$pp" >> ~/.profile
```

When invoked as a login shell, bash reads `.bash_profile` if present and, if not, it reads `~/.profile` (it will ignore `.profile` if `.bash_login` is present but I assume it isn't). So, the commands above will first save your desired path as `$pp` and then check whether a `~/.bash_profile` exists, add the path definition to it if it does and, if it doesn't, it will add it to `~/.profile`.

In the future, to avoid this kind of issue, use a function to add directories to your `$PATH`. Add these lines to your `~/.profile`:

```bash
pathmunge () 
{ 
    if ! echo "$PATH" | /bin/grep -Eq "(^|:)$1($|:)"; then
        if [ "$2" = "after" ]; then
            PATH="$PATH:$1";
        else
            PATH="$1:$PATH";
        fi;
    fi
}
```

Then, to add something to the beginning of your `$PATH`, add this line to `~/.profile`:

```bash
pathmunge "/path/to/foo"
```

And to add it to the end:

```bash
pathmunge "/path/to/foo" after
```

The function will only add a new directory to the `$PATH` if it isn't already there.

Comment: fwiw, my (unedited) `/etc/profile` on Fedora 34 has a `pathmunge` function that seems to have the same goal as the one you've shared. :)

Comment: @nishanthshanmugham yes, this function is included by default on Red Hat based systems. I originally took it from a Red Hat I was running circa 2004 or so.

Answer (score 4):

You have applied a hurricane of randomness to your configs!

If you cannot undo your edits to the files in `/etc`, you might have to reinstall `bash`!

You can adjust your personal `PATH` without changing any files in `/etc`. For example read [these answers](https://superuser.com/questions/1000867/a-more-comfortable-way-to-edit-a-long-path). I, of course, prefer my answer.

You could determine exactly where you are going astray by reading `man bash`, `man less`, and with one eye on the `INVOCATION` section of `man bash`, use `less` on the startup files. Whenever they seem to transfer control (`source`, `.`), use `less`'s `!` command to read that file. Use `less`'s `/` command to search for the string `PATH=` to find `PATH` assignments in each file. Remember to be as dumb as `bash`.

You could compare (with `diff`) the startup files (`.bashrc`,`.profile`, `.bash_login`) between your `$HOME` and that of " another user".

Answer (score 4):

To find all places where `$PATH` environment variable is changed use this:

```
sudo grep -rnw --exclude-dir={boot,dev,lib,media,mnt,proc,root,run,sys,/tmp,tmpfs,var} '/' -e "PATH="
```

This will search all directories on your system excluding virtual file system directories. In my case with three distros mounted, 697 files are returned.

---

A more targeted approach for OP is to search for specific path name. You could look for the program that is setting the unusual part of $PATH containing:

```
/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin
```

Run this in the terminal:

```
sudo grep -rnw --exclude-dir={boot,dev,lib,media,mnt,proc,root,run,sys,/tmp,tmpfs,var} '/' -e "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin"
```

If the first directory in the $PATH is not the culprit then search for the last one:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin
```

`grep` will return the name of the script / file that is setting the $PATH.

Comment: you are a life saver! Somebody changed the path in xinitrc of xfce4... I don't think I would have found that without your grep!