# How to find all instances where PATH is defined?

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, bashrc

In my `PATH` variable I see duplicate paths that I have no idea how they ended up there.

`/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/user/projects/bin:/snap/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin`

Note for instance the number of occurrences of `/snap/bin`.

I tried `grep` for the PATH but I couldn't find anything strange.
I also checked all the usual suspects `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, and the system wide definitions too, no luck.

EDIT: I am aware of the standard location where the `PATH` variable is set and read the answers to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705912/where-is-my-path-variable-being-set) and this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/1000867/a-more-comfortable-way-to-edit-a-long-path).

Comment: The first part is normal `/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin` Please post the configuration that added the `/home/user/projects/bin`

Comment: See my answer https://superuser.com/questions/1000867/a-more-comfortable-way-to-edit-a-long-path

Comment: @waltinator Your answer doesn't mention finding where the variable is defined.

Comment: You could run `grep -rws PATH /`, but it could take a while. Maybe just `grep -rws PATH /etc ~` would work. These might find lots of false positives though.

Comment: @BernardWei, if I knew I wouldn't have been asking...

Comment: @MSIS So you have no idea where this `/home/user/projects/bin` path is added? Try looking at `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/profile` and anythin in `/etc/profile.d/`