# Output the current PATH to text file using BASH script

Tags: bash

I am trying to output the PATH used by the computer to a simple text file.

Something like echo PATH >PATH.TXT or >>PATH.TXT

With the double >>, it works but gives each on a different line and if I use the single of course it overwrites the previous line with the next. Using %~dpo >PATH.TXT, or %~fo >>PATH.TXT, or even %~nx0 >>PATH.TXT does not give me the output I want.  Simply put I want to put the PATH into a text file for backup using a BATCH file incase I do something stupid like HELP PATH, which would change PATH completely.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. Are you trying to echo the output of the current $PATH or working directory to a text file? If so then you are nearly there, from the command line you would do `echo $PATH > file.txt` assuming you wanted to overwrite the contents of that file, use >> to append. Or do you want to find the current working directory of the script you are running? In other words when you execute you script are you looking to find the scripts current PATH or working directory from within the bash script?

Comment: This is almost certainly a Windows' cmd.exe question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change your `PATH` with command:

```
PATH=/new-path:$PATH
```

For example here is how to correctly expand the PATH:

```
$ PATH=/newpath:$PATH
$ echo $PATH
/newpath:/home/rick/bin:/home/rick/.local/bin:/mnt/e/bin:/mnt/e/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

Here is just one way to break your PATH (by omitting `$` prefix):

```
$ PATH=/brokenpath:PATH
$ echo $PATH
/brokenpath:PATH
```

If you mess up your PATH usually you can simply close your terminal and reopen it.

Omitting the `$` is the mistake made in your question as well. The method to capture PATH to text file is:

```
echo $PATH > PATH.TXT
```

To keep a running log of PATH changes you can use:

```
echo $PATH >> PATH.TXT
```

PATH is an environmental variable. To set the variable we use "PATH=" but to reference it's contents we need to use "$PATH".

---

The PATH variable can be set in many places as outlined in this Q&A: [Where is my PATH variable being set?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705912/where-is-my-path-variable-being-set). To discover which files are setting the PATH one of the answers recommends using:

```
grep --color -H 'PATH=' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login \
                     ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile \
                     /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null
```

On my machine the command returns:

```
/home/rick/.profile:PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh:    export PATH=$PATH:${snap_bin_path}
/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh:export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
/etc/environment:PATH="/mnt/e/bin:/mnt/e/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print your PATH to a text file with the following code:

```
echo $PATH >> PATH.txt
```

If you want to run a file to do this, be sure to add a shebang to the top:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $PATH >> PATH.txt
```